# Type annotation for a function returning a function taking args and kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing, mypy, type-annotation

The following example code works at runtime, but is not accepted by `mypy --strict`:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')


def log_call(msg: str) -> Callable[..., TypeT]:
    def do_call(func: Callable[..., TypeT], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> TypeT:
        print(msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return do_call


def double(val: int) -> int:
    return 2 * val


def plus(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


def plus_plus(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    return a + b + c


result_1 = log_call('hi')(double, 1)
result_2 = log_call('hi')(plus, 2, 3)
result_3 = log_call('hi')(plus_plus, 2, 3, 4)

result_4 = log_call('hi')(double, val=1)

print(result_1)
print(result_2)
print(result_3)
print(result_4)
```

`mypy` output:

```
test.py:26: error: Need type annotation for 'result_1'
test.py:27: error: Need type annotation for 'result_2'
test.py:28: error: Need type annotation for 'result_3'
test.py:30: error: Need type annotation for 'result_4'
test.py:32: error: Cannot determine type of 'result_1'
test.py:33: error: Cannot determine type of 'result_2'
test.py:34: error: Cannot determine type of 'result_3'
test.py:35: error: Cannot determine type of 'result_4'
```

Now instead of adding the type annotations to the `result*` variables, I would like to adjust the type annotation of the function, so the others can be deduced. This is my attempt:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')


def log_call(msg: str) -> Callable[[Callable[..., TypeT], Any, Any], TypeT]:
    def do_call(func: Callable[..., TypeT], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> TypeT:
        print(msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return do_call


def double(val: int) -> int:
    return 2 * val


def plus(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


def plus_plus(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    return a + b + c


result_1 = log_call('hi')(double, 1)
result_2 = log_call('hi')(plus, 2, 3)
result_3 = log_call('hi')(plus_plus, 2, 3, 4)

result_4 = log_call('hi')(double, val=1)

print(result_1)
print(result_2)
print(result_3)
print(result_4)
```

However now the number of parameters does not fit any more:

```
test.py:26: error: Too few arguments
test.py:28: error: Too many arguments
test.py:30: error: Unexpected keyword argument "val"
```

I guess I'm looking for something like

```
def log_call(msg: str) -> Callable[[Callable[..., TypeT], ...], TypeT]:
```

But this syntax is not legal.

Is there a way I could solve this?

Comment: You can't. Dynamic calls, `Any` and static type checking can't mix.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this is by making `log_call` a callable object. This separates the type annotations from the wrapper and the actual call. Also, since Python 3.10 it's possible to use `ParamSpec` to annotate input arguments (`*args` & `**kwargs`). This is a full example that passes `mypy --strict` and works:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")


class log_call:
    def __init__(self, msg: str) -> None:
        self.msg = msg

    def __call__(
        self, func: Callable[P, int], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs
    ) -> int:
        print(self.msg)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)


def double(val: int) -> int:
    return 2 * val


def plus(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b


def plus_plus(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    return a + b + c


result_1 = log_call("hi")(double, 1)
result_2 = log_call("hi")(plus, 2, 3)
result_3 = log_call("hi")(plus_plus, 2, 3, 4)
result_4 = log_call("hi")(double, val=1)

print(result_1)
print(result_2)
print(result_3)
print(result_4)
print(result_4)
print(result_4)
```